# Find parameter, which maximizes a function

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following function
$$ f(p,s,r) = \binom{s}{r}(p-1)^{r}$$
where $p,s,r$ are all positive and of course $s \ge r$ and $p \ge 1$.

I am interested in the variable $r$, which maximizes $f(p,s,r)$ for a given $p$ and $s$. The desired variable depends on $p$ and $s$.

For example, when $p=2$ (binary), then $r=\lceil \frac{s}{2} \rceil$, maximizes $f(2,s,r)$.

I would appreciate, if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: is $p$ an integer? is it greater than $1$?

Comment: @Med: Yes, $p,s,r$ are all integers and $\ge 1$ is right, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be as the following.

I have substituted $p-1$ with $p$.

start from $r=\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil$. Because $\binom {n}{k}=\binom {n}{n-k}$, we only check values of $r\geq\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil$ (assuming $p\geq1$).

$$f(p,s,\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil)=\binom{s}{\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil}p^{\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil}$$

in order to get the value

$$f(p,s,\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil+1)=\binom{s}{\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil+1}p^{\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil}+1$$

we need to multiply $f(p,s,\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil)$ by the following

$$\frac{s-\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil}{\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil+1}\times p$$

Note that we have used

$$\binom{x}{y}\times \frac{x-y}{y+1}=\binom{x}{y+1}$$

More generally,

$$f(p,s,\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil+(i+1))=f(p,s,\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil+i)\times\frac{s-\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil-i}{\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil+i+1}\times p, \hspace{10mm} i=0,1,2,...$$

Therefore, you need to check if the term that you are multiplying is greater than $1$ or not. So, check for which $i$ you have

$$\frac{s-\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil-i}{\lceil \frac{s}{2}\rceil+i+1}\times p\geq 1$$

Solving for $i$, you should find the maximum $i$ that satisfies the inequality. Note that as you increase $i$, the above fraction decreases.

Finally, what ever $i$ you find, $r=\lceil \frac{s}{2} \rceil+i+1$ would be your solution.

Comment: @N.Younger, glad it was helpful